# PDF letterhead as document background

Tags: letters, letterhead, backgrounds

My institution's letterhead is available as a PDF file.  The PDF is not just of the logo (to be placed in a corner), but of the entire page.  Is it possible to make this PDF the background of the first page of my document?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the [`wallpaper` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wallpaper/).  It has many options for creating background images that are tiled, centered, and scaled, on every page or only specific ones.  In your case if the letterhead is contained in `lh.pdf` then you simply need

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\ULCornerWallPaper{1}{lh.pdf}
\begin{document}
  Your text on the letterhead
\end{document}
```

The key command in this case is of course `\ULCornerWallPaper{<scale>}{<file>}` that places the image contained in `<file>` in the upper-left corner, scaled by a factor of `<scale>`.

Comment: didn't he say he wants the entire page, rather than just the logo on the corner?

Comment: Yes, but based on his description it sounded to me as if the file I called lh.pdf is the size of the entire page.  So when it's placed in the upper-left corner, it covers the whole page...

Comment: Thank you Michael for sharing this. Your tip has been extremely useful for some documents that I had to deal with recently.

Comment: I have certain PDF's that when used as wallpaper in this way (or `eos-pic` way) produce final PDF files that can not be opened by Acrobat Reader (but can be opened with Evince). I didn't find the pattern for this problem, any ideas?

Comment: If your output pdf, produced after the use of the `wallpaper` package, can be opened by Evince but not with Acrobat Reader, you can fix it using ghostscriptL `gs -o repaired.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress corrupted.pdf`. You can find more details on the [SuperUser site](http://superuser.com/questions/278562/how-can-i-fix-repair-a-corrupted-pdf-file).

Comment: Let me add to suggestions that I needed for this to work for me.  First, \ThisULCornerWallpaper with "This" added will put the letterhead only one one page - so if you only need the letterhead on page one add "This".  Secondly, straight use with a large letterhead may cause overlap of the .tex output and the letterhead.  To prevent this I pushed the start of the text down by using 
\null
\vskip .75in

Answer (score 10):

The package [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) allows to include a background image at each page but also on a single page.

Another option is to use the [`textpos`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) package that can put a box at a position on the page behind the text. It can be used together with `\includegraphics` and a PDF file.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a example with eso-pic, that uses frontpage.pdf for the first page and normalBackground.pdf for the rest.

First create 2 macros that can be used later.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\newcommand\BackgroundPicFront{
    \put(0,0){%
        \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{
            \vfill
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{frontpage}%
            \vfill
        }
    }
}

\newcommand\BackgroundPic{
    \put(0,0){%
        \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{
            \vfill
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{normalBackground}%
            \vfill
        }
    }
}
```

Then use those macros and don't forget to "clear"/"remove" the first background when you add the next background.

```
% Sets the background
\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPicFront}

% Unsets the background
\ClearShipoutPicture

% Sets another background
\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPic}
```

Have fun

Comment: Johan, it looks like the two `\BackgroundPic*` commands do exactly the same thing except that they use two different image files.  Is there any reason why they couldn't be defined as LaTeX commands with an argument, so that there is only one new command needed?  Also, am I correct that if, after the first page, plain paper is needed, then there is no need to call `\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPic}` after `\ClearShipoutPicture`?

Comment: Added a `%` after the `\put(0,0){`. The image was shifted a bit to the right without the `%`.

Comment: @Mars you're correct, if you want to just set one background, you don't have to call `\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPic}` after the `\ClearShipoutPicture`