# Placing a float at a specified position

Tags: floats, positioning

I have a bunch of coordinates generated by a program and the text of the bodies of corresponding figures, e.g.:

```
\includegraphics{abc.png}
\caption{abc}
\label{fig:abc}
```

I was wondering if there is some way to place a figure at specified absolute coordinates (say, page 1, x = 245px, y=452px).

I have seen [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24663/how-to-place-a-floating-text-box-at-a-specified-location-in-page-coordinates), but it doesn't work for figures (which don't go into boxes)

As for why I can't just use non-floats, I'm working with **existing documents** and don't want to go through everything and manually convert to something different. I was thinking maybe something like this would work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\newcommand{\fakefigure}[1]{
    \renewcommand{\label}[1]{}
    \renewcommand{\caption}[1]{\captionof{figure}{#1}}
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\fakefigure{
    \includegraphics{abc.png}
    \caption{abc}
    \label{fig:abc}
}
\end{document}
```

And then I could put *that* in the box from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24663/how-to-place-a-floating-text-box-at-a-specified-location-in-page-coordinates). But I'm not sure if there are some other commands I need to trap to make that work.

Comment: There is but you must not put it in a figure environment; which flots by definition. For the caption, you can use `\captionof{figure}{caption text}`.

Comment: @Bernard I am doing this programmatically so trying to strip out everything seems difficult. If I were to say `\def\caption{\captionof{fig:abc}` and `\renewcommand\label[1]{}` would it work?

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example which we can copy-paste-compile to help you. Certainly what you just suggested won't work. For one thing, you're missing a curly bracket. More generally, what would that be meant to do? Note that the primary problem here is the use of the `figure` environment. You need not to use it. You don't even have to have a caption if you don't want. If you do want, that's a secondary issue. The main point is: if you don't want something to float, don't make it a float. A figure is a float. Floats, by design, float. That's kind of their raison d'être.

Comment: @cfr I can't just not use floats because I'm trying to modify existing documents and want to make as few changes as possible.

Comment: @k_g - Sorry to have to say it, but the answer is "your objective cannot be achieved with `figure` environments". No way, no how. Time to start looking into using the `\captionof` macro.

Comment: @Mico so if I'm not tied to using figure environments, but want to replicate the figure interface so that I get something that *looks* like a figure but can be placed manually, would my example above work in general?

Comment: If you don't want it to float then `as few changes as possible` includes making it not a float.

Comment: If you can use `\fakefigure` then you are talking about not using `figure`, right? So that involves conversion from float to non-float.

Comment: You cannot `\renewcommand\caption ...` like that because `\captionof` is defined in terms of `\caption` by the `capt-of` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way of making the `\fakefigure` macro suggested in the question work. Well, at least it survives minimal testing in combination with [Werner's answer on absolute placement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24675/).

The proposed redefinition of `\caption` won't work because `capt-of` defines `\captionof` in terms of `\caption`. However, it is possible to first save the definition of `\caption` and then use the saved definition when redefining `\caption`.

```
\global\let\oldcaption\caption
\renewcommand\caption{\def\@captype{figure}\oldcaption}% modified from capt-of
```

I've only allowed for `figure` type elements here. If you need other kinds of floats to be converted to non-floats, you'd want to reinstitute the optional argument provided by `capt-of`.

We can then combine this with [Mico's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/310731/) to create the `\fakefigure{}` macro:

```
\makeatletter
\global\let\oldcaption\caption
\newcommand{\fakefigure}[1]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \renewcommand\caption{\def\@captype{figure}\oldcaption}% modified from capt-of
    #1
  \end{minipage}%
}
\makeatother
```

This then allows us to write something like

```
\placetextbox{.35}{,3}{%
  \fakefigure{%
    \includegraphics[height=.2\textheight]{tiger}%
    \caption{abc}%
    \label{fig:abc}%
  }%
}
```

to place TeX's standard tiger at an arbitrary position on the page.

[image: tiger at arbitrary position]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,kantlipsum,eso-pic}
\makeatletter
\global\let\oldcaption\caption
\newcommand{\fakefigure}[1]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \renewcommand\caption{\def\@captype{figure}\oldcaption}% modified from capt-of
    #1
  \end{minipage}%
}
\makeatother
% from Werner's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24675/
\newcommand{\placetextbox}[3]{% \placetextbox{<horizontal pos>}{<vertical pos>}{<stuff>}
  \setbox0=\hbox{#3}% box
  \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{% Add <stuff> to current page foreground
    \put(\LenToUnit{#1\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{#2\paperheight}){\vtop{{\null}\makebox[0pt][c]{#3}}}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\placetextbox{0.5}{0.5}{\fbox{\Huge\textsf{This is my text.}}}
\placetextbox{0.5}{1}{\Huge\texttt{Here is another piece of text.}}
\placetextbox{0.1}{0.1}{\Large $\mathcal{A}_1$}
\placetextbox{.35}{,3}{%
  \fakefigure{%
    \includegraphics[height=.2\textheight]{tiger}%
    \caption{abc}%
    \label{fig:abc}%
  }%
}
\kant[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're looking for, you may want to pursue the following approach: Using the facilities of your text editor,

- globally replace all instances of `\begin{figure}` with

  ```
  \par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
  ```
- globally replace all instances of `\end{figure}` with

  ```
  \end{minipage}
  ```

  and
- globally replace all instances of figure-related `\caption` statements with

  ```
  \captionof{figure}
  ```

  If your document has any `table` environments, don't modify the table-related `\caption` statements.

What this will still be lacking, relative to a (now no-longer floating) `figure` environment, is the vertical spacing LaTeX would insert above and below the environment, as needed. As you seem to want to place these environments in arbitrary places on a page, I trust this won't be a shortcoming.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out and hopefully it works. (Actually, I'm writing a program to do this, but hopefully the process is the same)

Comment: @k_g - If you can use LuaLaTeX and are familiar with the basics of Lua programming, it's straightforward to program up a Lua function that acts as a preprocessor and does these replacements before LaTeX starts its normal processing.

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually using python for the rest of it, and this doesn't seem all that complicated.

But can I set the exact position of a minipage?

Comment: @k_g - There are quite a few postings on this site about to go about achieving exact positioning of various objects on a page.