# How do I put a picture "in front of text" in LaTeX?

Tags: graphics

I believe most of us are familiar with the Microsoft Word settings for a picture in a text document. In particular, there is one option called "in front of text" that just lets you put the picture wherever you want, ignoring everything else in the document.

Is there something like this in LaTeX? I was thinking of an instruction that could include the "coordinates" of the picture in the document.

Comment: Search for the overlay option in Tikz.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6185

Comment: 'I believe most of us are familiar with the Microsoft Word settings for a picture in a text document. ' On this site? Are you kidding?

Comment: What, you turned on a computer for the first time and started writing in LaTeX?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to place a "floating text box" at a specified location in page coordinates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24663/5764)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- For details see [Absolute positioning in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6185).
- I use `tikz` with `remember picture` and `overlay`.
- `remember picture` is for absolute positioning.
- `overlay` makes that the picture has the size of zero and therefore doesn't influence the position of other objects (as far as I understand).

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

% Demo
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[xshift=65mm,yshift=-48mm,anchor=north west] at (current page.north west){%
    \includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]