# How to insert a rotated side-note/textbox without any border, in a document?

Tags: graphics, positioning

I need it to be repeated in every page of the document at a fixed position.The flow of the text hasn't to be involved. It comes to two signatures in a contract. They have to assume a vertical position.
What if I wanted to exclude some pages from the change? Generally the last one in a contract. Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to place a "floating text box" at a specified location in page coordinates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24663/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following inserts an 12cm, rotated

```
Signature: _______________  Signature: _______________
```

in the `F`ore`G`round of every page at the vertical centre of the text block, 1in into the right margin. Code is commented to highlight the positioning:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtTextLowerLeft{%
    \hspace*{\textwidth}% Move to LowerRight of Text block
    \hspace*{1in}% Move 1in into the right margin
    \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\textheight-.5\height}{% Move image to vertical centre
      \rotatebox{90}{% Rotate 90 degrees
        \makebox[12cm]{Signature: \hrulefill \quad Signature: \hrulefill}}}% Insert signature(s)
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\sloppy\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]% Your document content

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind and prompt reply. This is a wonderful community. I am a Latex's beginner. However I would need to insert a text like this: Signature_________________________ Signature __________How have I to modify that piece of code?

Comment: @Gianluca: See the updated answer.