# how to place a non-floating figure using x,y page coordinates?

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning

I wish to know if is it possible to place a non-floating figure using x,y page coordinates? Also above other figure or text

For example. The yellow rectangle is the area where I wish to place my figure

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24663/how-to-place-a-floating-text-box-at-a-specified-location-in-page-coordinates?rq=1

Comment: Do you need the text to automatically flow around the figure, or will you manually address that issue yourself?  To place thing absolutely on the page, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page

Comment: The pgfmanual describes in section 17.13.2 how to place figures on top of  page. If you want to place it relative to some text element, I recommend the `tikzmark` library.