# 90° rotated text in custom sidebar of beamer

Tags: beamer, sidebar

So I want to have a sidebar in my custom beamer theme, where I have a short text with the Copyrights. The text should be rotated by 90°. I think I will first have to create the sidebar in the *beameroutertheme.sty* and edit it until I get the disiered effect. Unfortunatly I am not capable of this so you maybe you guys can help me?
Below is a picture how i would imagine it. The rest of the themework is already done.

[image]

Comment: Hello, it would be helpful if we had an MWE to work with. What is the current problem? The rotating or positioning the text? Rotating could be done with `\rotatebox{90}{My institute}`

Comment: Positioning may be done with this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24663/how-to-place-a-floating-text-box-at-a-specified-location-in-page-coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look if this meets the requirements

Position of the text can be shifted up\down by deleting the  `\vfill` and alternatively using `\vskip` or `\vspace` commands

Graphics image can be used by uncommenting the `\includegraphics` line

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 \useoutertheme[height=0pt,left,width=1cm]{sidebar}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{use=structure,bg=structure.fg!20!white,fg=red}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][.98\paperheight][t]{1cm}%
        \vfill%
        \centering
        % \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image}
         \rotatebox{90}{@ myinstitute logo}
         \vfill      
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{sidebar}
        \insertframenumber
        \vskip1.5em%
    \end{minipage}
}
\makeatother

\title{Sample title}
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{Overleaf}
\date{2014}


\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
This is a text in the first frame. This is a text in the first frame. This is a text in the first frame.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```