# A clean letter class for office use, including serial letters

Tags: templates, letters

I'm using LaTeX for writing corporate letters, including serials letters. To incorporate our organization's logo, back address and so on I put a single A4-sized PDF containing all this information into the background using the `dinbrief` class:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{dinbrief} 
...

\setbottomtexttop{270mm}  % x from top of page
\bottomtext{\kern27mm%    % y from bottom of page; x+y=297mm = DIN A4 height
        \vbox to 0pt{\vss\hbox to 0pt{\kern-2.5cm
        \includegraphics{letterheads/head-lzi-cl.pdf}\hss}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Prof. Drov Nuts\\St. Anford}
..
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

This seems somewhat hackish. Is there an alternative for a clean letter style? Most letter styles I've seen try to use LaTeX for placing fancy logos and back addresses which I think are much better included from a single nicely designed PDF. Are there any classes supporting this idea?

Edit: [PDF letterhead as document background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/837/pdf-letterhead-as-document-background) seems relevant here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the »scrlttr2« class from the [KOMA Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle. It supports serial letters and is very flexible. The manual has the details.

Comment: I looked at the manual and while the class seems flexible it also seems to demand an existing layout to be decomposed into several images before they can be included in the background (Kapitel 4). Does `scrlttr2` support languages other than German?

Comment: Language specification is not a matter of the document class. This letter class allows to set up a custom letterhead. So inserting a graphical logo should be no big deal.

Comment: @Torsten German and English letters typically use a different format for dates or how they name attachments. I was referring to those aspects because I expected that a document class must take care of them.

Comment: Take a look at the [KOMA Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) documentation. It will answer your questions. The class is more flexible than you think and supports many different formats by so called »Letter Class Options«.