# Letter class alternatives with support for figures, tables, and labels

Tags: floats, letters

I'm increasingly fed up with the arbitrary restrictions that the standard LaTeX letter class has. Today I discovered that the table environment is not defined in the standard letter class, which means one can't use labels or captions.

CTAN has a [list of letter related packages](http://www.ctan.org/keyword/letters).
Can anyone suggest a good LaTeX letter class to work with for general use? I'd like something as flexible and with as few restrictions as possible, well maintained, not excessively complicated to use, and not buggy. I was earlier recommended `newlfm` (on comp.text.tex). [That post](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/6068f2e617ac5b36/1c319a28bd48ab4c) was about the fact that the letter class does not allow the addition of a subject.

A similar question has been asked already, ["A clean letter class for office use, including serial letters"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10278/a-clean-letter-class-for-office-use-including-serial-letters), where `scrlttr2` is recommended.

Comment: I've run into this issue trying to use figures in a letter - I get the error "environment figure undefined"

Comment: @David: What alternatives are you considering?

Comment: I was considering article, report until I found this answer, in the future I will give scrlttr2 a try.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I recommend using the scrlttr2 class.

- It is extremely flexible
- It is actively maintained
- It is stable since many years; if there would occur any bug I'm sure the author would deal with it quickly
- There are templates ([German example](http://www.matthiaspospiech.de/latex/vorlagen/#toc-briefe-mit-koma-script))
- The class includes concepts which distinguish it from other classes, such as variables, pseudo lengths
- You can use option files to store macros or to extend functionality
- You could even use `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, `\paragraph` and `\minisec`: the KOMA-Script author provides the option file [`sections.lco`](http://www.komascript.de/sections.lco) for it, with an example
- It benefits from features of the [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle
- You can use `scrpage2` with it for header and footer
- You can use tables and figures with captions, for example if you load the [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) and the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package
- Here's a German presentation about separation of content and presentation using scrlttr2: [briefdemo.pdf](http://www.komascript.de/files/briefdemo.pdf) ([source code](http://www.komascript.de/files/linuxtag-briefdemos_2005-06-26.zip))

Originally, the KOMA-Script manual, including the sclttr2 documentation, has been written [in German](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguide.pdf), also published as a book. There's an [english translation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.pdf), which could be a bit behind the most current features (currently 2011-05-30).

As a general remark: I expect a letter class to provide letter functionality, a book class to offer book features etc. - not a class to do all. There are many classes for different purposes and even if one uses two classes, the results can be merged.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I see `scrlttr2` allows use of a subject. Do you know whether you can use the table environment, or is this something I'll have to find out for myself?

Comment: It doesn't look like the table environment is defined here either. What a drag. Does anyone know why it isn't?

Comment: @Faheem: Floats are not defined by the letter classes are these are unlikely to be appropriate. You can use a `tabular` just fine, but it will not float (or have a caption).

Comment: @Faheem: it's because floating tables and figures are very unusual in letters. It's more common to write a letter and to provide another possibly big document as appendix, for separate use.

Comment: @Faheem: your question is very general, about suggesting a letter class for general use. Perhaps post a specific follow-up question such as "How can I use tables with captions with scrlttr2" or similar. It's possible.

Comment: @Stefan: Ok, will do. I don't see why a LaTeX class should second guess possible uses. What is the harm to allowing floats?

Comment: @Joseph: I don't understand what you mean by appropriate. What about a letter as part of a scientific correspondence? This could reasonably be expected to have tables and/or figures in it.

Comment: @Faheem: Quite apart from the fact that nowadays you'd send an e-mail, I really can't imagine that *many* people would every want to include a floating figure in a letter. It's also worth bearing in mind that for the `letter` class, this was a decision made when computational resources were much more limited and the saving on omitting this functionality was probably worth it. If/when we get LaTeX3 done, the plan would be to have functionality essentially the same across classes.

Comment: @Faheem: even in a scientific correspondence, separating letter and document would be a good idea. For example, the document could be fowarded without the letter or it could be worked on, such as revised and sent back.

Comment: Please note, that the author of KOMA-Script [no longer supports `section.lco`](https://komascript.de/comment/4905#comment-4905) and instead recommends the use of the `scrletter` package together with a documentclass such as `scrartcl`.

Comment: The link above is dead, but I found an archived copy on IA, which is https://web.archive.org/web/20210125170801/https://komascript.de/comment/4905. The relevant (German) comment is almost at the end of the page. Here is the English translation, courtesy of Google.

Comment: "Now obsolete It should be noted that the scrletter package is now included in KOMA-Script. This allows writing a scrlttr2 style letter with the classes scrbook, scrreprt or scrartcl. This allows you to use all the options of these classes, not just structuring commands, but also the table of contents, bibliography, index, floating environments, etc. in a letter. The use of section.lco is therefore no longer recommended. The support for this lco file is definitely ended."

Answer (score 7):

I've never quite seen the advantage of a letter class. I just use `article` class (plus a letterhead package that I wrote for my university.) Using the `article` class obviously solves the problems with respect to undefined environments in (some of) the letter classes.

For mail merge type documents I use the [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) package, which allows me to store the addresses in a `.csv` file and allows an unlimited number of fields as needed. The documentation has examples of using it for mail merge.  Here's an example of how I use it: [Example of mailmerge package with an Excel spreadsheet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34151/2693). But my needs are quite minimal, so this may not be the best solution for everyone.

Comment: I don't understand why a reply basically saying that a letter class is not useful is voted up so much. Is this really something that many of you believe?

Comment: I think this discussion shouldn't take place in the comments, so I've replied in chat. What's "useful" is a pretty subjective (and your question borders on that, too.) The main functionality that I have for letters is (i) my university letterhead and (ii) mail merge capability.  (i) can't be solved by a generic letter class, and (ii) can be solved very well with `datatool`. So for me, (and others, I suspect) there's no need for a specific letter class.

Comment: Is your package for the letterhead publicly available? If so, you could answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296443/5645

Comment: @MartinThoma no my package is only distributed internally. But it doesn't provide the functionality you seek anyway.