# Example of mailmerge package with an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: letters

I am looking for an example for using the [`mailmerge`](http://ctan.org/mailmerge) package to write a cover letter, with names and addresses on a spreadsheet. The package comes with an example, but you have to manually enter all the data.

Comment: Have you looked at the `datatool` (http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/datatool) package? I've done what you're talking about with it and a database in .csv file.

Comment: You might be interested in the [UK-TUG templates page](http://uk.tug.org/training/templates/), which includes a mail merge demo amongst other things.

Comment: @JosephWright these templates need some updates! The thesis templates uk.tug.org/training/thesis/ are woefully outdated! For example, would you be happy to consider posting my thesis template for Imperial College London, to the UK Tug page? I have passed my PhD viva and done final upload after corrections.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I use the [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) package. I don't use the `letter` document class, since I use my own letterhead package plus the `article` class. But the basics of how to do this should be clear, and adaptable to `letter` class. It's important to do checks for empty fields in address lines, otherwise you will get blank lines.

I use the `parskip` package with letters, which sets the `\parindent` to 0 and uses blank lines to separate paragraphs.  If you don't like this, then you may want to set the address lines in a `{tabular}{@{}l}` environment instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{parskip}

\makeatletter
% Blank/missing fields commands
% \skipblank adds \\ to filled field; * version adds \space instead of newline
\newcommand\skipblank{\@ifstar\@spskip\@nlskip}
\newcommand\@nlskip[1]{\ifthenelse{\DTLiseq{#1}{}}{\relax}{#1\\}}
\newcommand\@spskip[1]{\ifthenelse{\DTLiseq{#1}{}}{\relax}{#1\space}}
% \checkblank replaces blank fields with ***
\newcommand\checkblank[1]{\ifthenelse{\DTLiseq{#1}{}}{***}{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb{addresses}{mail-merge-addresses.csv} % use your actual address database here
\DTLforeach*{addresses}{%
    \addtitle=Title,
    \firstname=FirstName,
    \lastname=LastName,
    \position=Position,
    \addressi=Address1,
    \addressii=Address2,
    \addressiii=Address3,
    \city=City,
    \state=State,
    \zip=Zip,
    \country=Country}
    {%
\setcounter{page}{1}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\checkblank{\addtitle}\ \firstname\ \lastname,\\
\skipblank{\position}
\skipblank{\addressi}
\skipblank{\addressii}
\skipblank{\addressiii}
\city, \state\ \zip\\
\skipblank*{\country}

Dear \checkblank{\addtitle}\ \lastname:

This is the text of the letter.

Sincerely,


\clearpage
}
\end{document}
```

The `mail-merge-addresses.csv` file is the following: (It deliberately has blank fields to illustrate the field checking.)

```
Title,  LastName,   FirstName,  Position,   Address1,   Address2,   Address3,   City,   State,  Zip,    Country
Dr.,    Smith,  James,  Chair,  Dept. of Physics,   University of Somewhere,    434 East Hall,  Cambridge,  MA, 02139,  
Mr.,    Jones,  Bill,   Director of Human Resources,    ,   University of Nowhere,  A203 King St.,  Stanford,   CA, 94305,  
,   Brown,  Sally,  ,   Firstline,  ,   3rdline,    East Lansing,   MI, ,   USA
```