# Filling LaTeX template programatically

Tags: templates, scripts

I have an offical document template in LaTeX, which I would like to fill programatically, i.e. providing script with values for selected variables (e.g. name, surname or boolean value for Mr./Mrs.) and compiling .tex into .pdf.

1. How do I correctly create a document with such variables, is there some common format for inserting such templated variables into LaTeX?
2. How do I compile such template from a script (I need just pointing into the right direction, the right way to do these kind of things, I will know where to go from there)?

Comment: An idea: variables could just be ordinary TeX macros, defined in a file which is `\input`(ted) by the main file; you should then use the piped input facility to generate this definition file dynamically and feed it to the TeX compiler.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the `datatool` package, too.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89803/11604

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: The question states a template is available and then asks how to create on. It might be possible this question is asking about template engines. I vote to close as unclear.

Comment: @Johannes_B why do you want to have it closed instead of just asking me to clarify it?

Comment: @syntagma Please clarify.