# How to generate personalized PDF documents from a LaTeX file linked to a text file or database with the names

Tags: csv, database

Say you need to generate certificates of assitance to a course. You compose a LaTeX document and want to link it to a CSV or a database file, where the names of the assistants are stored. Is Latexdb an option for this? Are there other options for text files?

Comment: There are several packages to work with CSV or database import, e.g. the datatool package. See also [data-import on CTAN](https://ctan.org/topic/data-import).

Comment: Does one of the questions in the "Related" sidebar answer your question? For example this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89793/mail-merging-documents-from-a-database?

Comment: @Fritz I'm missing some more information on how to link to databases.

Comment: @nightcod3r - As always, it would be helpful if you could post some compilable code or at least flesh out your question a bit more to avoid wild guessing on what you want to do exactly... Anyway. You might want to try [csvsimple](https://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple)

Comment: @nightcod3r In datatool package, there are also guidelines how to connect to database files. It heavily depends upon which type of file you want to connect - for .csv, you can use csv simple or datatool, for .xls datatool, for .xlsx or .accdb you will have to get a little further - I am using python and pythonTeX ; also with ruby it is possible.
Also depends, how much data and which type you have.
For example, reading long text from database (paragraphs) will require you to use outside program or script, to "crunch it" for datatool. Also, special characters are issue.

Comment: @nightcod3r I am actually dealig with this, so you should post something more specific, for anybody to propose anything specific in return.