# Letter with different addressees

Tags: automation, letters

I would like to generate several cover letters which except for the title and the address of the recipients are identical. I do not want to change the title and address every time, but rather want to have latex go through the list of titles and substitutes them in the right place and generate the PDF file. Is it possible?

Comment: Probably this is what you are looking for: [Example of mailmerge package with an Excel spreadsheet](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34151)