# Mail merge using datatool with letter class

Tags: letters, datatool

I am trying to adapt this [question/answer on how to do mail merge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34151/example-of-mailmerge-package-with-an-excel-spreadsheet) to work with the `letter` document class.

The linked answer works great for me, but when I try to change the document class to `letter` I keep getting an `error| Argument on \@tempc has an extra }`, but it seems that my braces are balanced. Are `letter` and `datatool` incompatible? Here is my example. How can I better understand this error? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{parskip}

\signature{Richard Herron}
\address{New York, NY}

\makeatletter
% Blank/missing fields commands
% \skipblank adds \\ to filled field
% * version adds \space instead of newline
\newcommand\skipblank{\@ifstar\@spskip\@nlskip}
\newcommand\@nlskip[1]{\ifthenelse{\DTLiseq{#1}{}}{\relax}{#1\\}}
\newcommand\@spskip[1]{\ifthenelse{\DTLiseq{#1}{}}{\relax}{#1\space}}
% \checkblank replaces blank fields with ***
\newcommand\checkblank[1]{\ifthenelse{\DTLiseq{#1}{}}{***}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{addresses}{mail-merge-addresses.csv} 
\DTLforeach*{addresses}{%
    \addtitle=Title,
    \firstname=FirstName,
    \lastname=LastName,
    \position=Position,
    \addressi=Address1,
    \addressii=Address2,
    \addressiii=Address3,
    \city=City,
    \state=State,
    \zip=Zip,
\country=Country}
{%
    \begin{letter}{\checkblank{\addtitle}\ \firstname\ \lastname\\
        \skipblank{\position}
        \skipblank{\addressi}
        \skipblank{\addressii}
        \skipblank{\addressiii}
        \city, \state\ \zip\\
        \skipblank*{\country}
    }

    \opening{Dear \checkblank{\addtitle}\ \lastname,}

    This is the text of the letter.

    \closing{Sincerely,}

\end{letter}
}

\end{document}
```

Edit: I should add that I'm using the same .csv file database that the linked answer uses, but I get the same results if I remove the blank entries.

```
Title,  LastName,   FirstName,  Position,   Address1,   Address2,   Address3,   City,   State,  Zip,    Country
Dr.,    Smith,  James,  Chair,  Dept. of Physics,   University of Somewhere,    434 East Hall,  Cambridge,  MA, 02139,  
Mr.,    Jones,  Bill,   Director of Human Resources,    ,   University of Nowhere,  A203 King St.,  Stanford,   CA, 94305,  
,   Brown,  Sally,  ,   Firstline,  ,   3rdline,    East Lansing,   MI, ,   USA
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument to `\begin{letter}` is massaged in order to extract the addressee. This massage is incompatible with `\ifthenelse`.

Here's a way out: we fed the argument in “explicit” form.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[businessenvelope]{envlab}
\makelabels

\signature{Richard Herron}
\address{New York, NY}

\makeatletter
% Blank/missing fields commands
% \skipblank adds \\ to filled field
% * version adds \space instead of newline
\newcommand\skipblank{\@ifstar\@spskip\@nlskip}
\newcommand\@nlskip[1]{\ifthenelse{\DTLiseq{#1}{}}{\relax}{#1\\}}
\newcommand\@spskip[1]{\ifthenelse{\DTLiseq{#1}{}}{\relax}{#1\space}}
% \checkblank replaces blank fields with ***
\newcommand\checkblank[1]{\ifthenelse{\DTLiseq{#1}{}}{***}{#1}}

\newtoks\address@toks
\newcommand\addto@address[1]{%
  \address@toks=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\address@toks#1}%
}
\newcommand\makeaddress{%
  \address@toks={}%
  \ifthenelse{\DTLiseq{\addtitle}{}}{\addto@address{***\ }}{\addto@address{\addtitle\ }}%
  \addto@address{\firstname\ }%
  \addto@address{\lastname}%
  \addto@address{\noexpand\\}
  \ifthenelse{\DTLiseq{\position}{}}{}{\addto@address{\position\\}}
  \ifthenelse{\DTLiseq{\addressi}{}}{}{\addto@address{\addressi\\}}
  \ifthenelse{\DTLiseq{\addressii}{}}{}{\addto@address{\addressii\\}}
  \ifthenelse{\DTLiseq{\addressiii}{}}{}{\addto@address{\addressiii\\}}
  \addto@address{\city, }\addto@address{\state\ }\addto@address{\zip}
  \ifthenelse{\DTLiseq{\country}{}}{}{\addto@address{\noexpand\\}}
  \ifthenelse{\DTLiseq{\country}{}}{}{\addto@address{\country}}
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\begin{letter}{\the\address@toks}}\x
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{addresses}{mail-merge-addresses.csv} 
\DTLforeach*{addresses}{%
    \addtitle=Title,
    \firstname=FirstName,
    \lastname=LastName,
    \position=Position,
    \addressi=Address1,
    \addressii=Address2,
    \addressiii=Address3,
    \city=City,
    \state=State,
    \zip=Zip,
\country=Country}
{%
 \makeaddress
    \opening{Dear \checkblank{\addtitle}\ \lastname,}

    This is the text of the letter.

    \closing{Sincerely,}

\end{letter}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That does it. Thanks! But now I have another question. My MWE was too M. When I add back `\usepackage{hyperref}`, `\usepackage[businessenvelope]{envlab}`, and `\makelabels` I get `illegal number in definition`. Can I not add back envelopes? Would I be better served doing this operation in Python? Or even R? Thanks!

Comment: @RichardHerron I've changed the implementation, making all the address field without using the `\skipblank` and similar commands. I don't think that `hyperref` makes much sense with letters.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why I get two numbered pages that are blank except for $ \Delta = \Delta $ ?

Comment: @RichardHerron There was an error, it should be fixed now, see the edit history.