# How to get a bunch of letters/envelopes (PDF) from a list of clients (CSV)?

Tags: automation, letters, excel

Say I have a letter like this:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\signature{Joe Bloggs}
\address{21 Bridge Street \\ Smallville \\ Dunwich DU3 4WE}
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Director \\ Doe \& Co \\ 35 Anthony Road
\\ Newport \\ Ipswich IP3 5RT}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}

I am writing to you on behalf of the Wikipedia project (http://www.wikipedia.org/),
an endeavour to build a fully-fledged multilingual encyclopaedia in an entirely
open manner, to ask for permission to use your copyrighted material.

% The \ldots command produces dots in a way that will not upset
% the typesetting of the document.
\ldots 

That said, allow me to reiterate that your material will be used to the noble end of
providing a free collection of knowledge for everyone; naturally enough, only if you
agree. If that is the case, could you kindly fill in the attached form and post it
back to me? We shall greatly appreciate it.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

I look forward to your reply.

\closing{Yours Faithfully,}

\ps

P.S. You can find the full text of GFDL license at
\url{http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html}.

\encl{Copyright permission form}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

And say I have a list of clients like this:

[image]

How can I run a loop through my list of clients to produce letters and envelopes for each one so that each is addressed correctly?

Comment: Duplicate? [Example of mailmerge package with an Excel spreadsheet](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34151)

Comment: Ooo! How juicy! Will take a look. Should I delete this duplicate?

Comment: You can if you like, or we can just close it as a duplicate which means the question will stay around but will be linked to the one I listed.

Comment: Yeah, just delete it.

Comment: You  need to do that yourself (there should be a link below the question for you.)