# Adding sectioning support in scrlttr2 class

Tags: sectioning, letters, scrlttr2

It seems like by default the `scrlttr2` class doesn't support sectioning, that is the command `\section` or `\paragraph` returns errors.

How can one add sectioning support to a latter basing on `scrlttr2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is hinted in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25064/412). In particular, download the file [sectionslco.zip](http://www.komascript.de/files/sectionslco.zip) and unzip it to the directory containing the letter. Finally, add the class option `sections`. Now you can use all sectioning macros, e.g. `\section`, as usual.

Comment: Now obsolete and unsupported.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using an `scrartcl` document together with the `scrletter` package which comes with Koma-Script for a few years now.  It allows you to put a `letter` environment into any document, effectively enabling sections *inside* and *after* your main letter.

## Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter} % You can put most scrlttr2 options here.
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\date{\today}
\setkomavar{fromname}{My Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{My address\\My City}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{Phone Number}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{mail@example.com}
\setkomavar{place}{City}
\setkomavar{signature}{My name again}

\setkomavar{subject}{Hello World}
\begin{letter}[fontsize=14pt]{%
    To:\\ You
}
\opening{Hello there!}

Hello dear world.

\section{Oh wow!}

This is another section.

\closing{CU later}
\ps{PS: Forgot anything?}
\encl{A bottle of beer}
\end{letter}

\tableofcontents % Even hyperrefs into the main letter work.
\section{Another section}
With content.
\end{document}
```