# What is a sound way to add wrapped figure support to a letter?

Tags: floats, wrapfigure, letters

I am using the `letter` class and would like to put a wrapped figure in the letter.  How can this be done properly?

Attempting to insert a wrapped figure using the `wrapfig` package (with a caption) fails.  The following is a workaround I stumbled upon but don't fully understand.  I posted it as responding to a special case of this item:  [Letter class alternatives with support for figures, tables, and labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25061/letter-class-alternatives-with-support-for-figures-tables-and-labels/).  It was deleted there (after some upvotes), presumably because a moderator felt it was raising a different question rather than providing a sound workaround.  So I'm posting it as a separate issue. I mention the deleted post for context; readers may find related content there.

With the letter class, attempting to put a caption in a `wrapfig` environment with a standard `\caption{}` command gives an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: No counter 'figure' defined.
```

The same error appears if I use `\caption*{}` (evidently the counter is being used even though the count is not used in the caption).  Adding a new figure counter only makes other errors appear.

I tried again, using `\usepackage{caption}`.  This gives a different error:

```
! Package caption Error: No float type 'figure' defined.
```

This happens with both `\caption{}` and `\caption*{}`.  Just as a shot in the dark, I tried adding:

```
\newcounter{figure}
```

After doing so, `\caption*{}` works fine, although a plain `\caption{}` gives an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<write> \@writefile{\ext@figure ...
```

Further adding the following in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ext@figure{}
\makeatother
```

makes the error go away, and produces correct captions, including correctly incrementing figure numbers.

I don't understand exactly what is going on "under the covers" that is making this workaround effective, but it works.  I'd like to understand why it works, or a more correct solution.

Note that the regular figure `environment` remains unavailable.

In summary, my preamble has:

```
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
% caption will raise "No float type 'figure'" w/i wrapfigure unless
% a figure counter is defined; ext@figure prevents further errors
\newcounter{figure}
\makeatletter
\def\ext@figure{}
\makeatother
```

Is there a better way to get a wrapped figure in a letter?

Comment: Heiko Oberdiek offered the following explanatory comment to the deleted post before it was deleted: \ext@figure usually expands to lof that is used by \addcontentsline to write the entry for the list of figures. If a list of figures is not needed, then the workaround looks fine. If \ext@figure expands to something that is not known, then the write order will be ignored. However, \ext@figure must be expandable in order to survive a \csname construct. Thus \def\ext@figure{} works and \let\ext@figure\relax does not. –

Comment: If you have a letter with a single? image in it why does it need a numbered caption?, you can just include the image and put a paragraph of text under it.

Comment: In fact the letter in question only needed a single figure and I didn't need the numbered caption.  I included information about experimenting with numbered captions here in case others might seek that capability.