# Graphics, graphicx, and Texlive2014

Tags: graphics

I am setting up my install of texlive2014 and working on my first document.

I want to insert a small graphic on a page, and have the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{letter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\collegename}{TK}


\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=10mm]
{/home/steven/doc/app/assets/image/s-stamp.tif}
\centering
\end{figure}
```

When I run `latex` I get this error:

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: Environment figure undefined.
```

My first suspicion was that I've made a mistake with my markup. My second suspicion is that maybe Texlive2014 doesn't come with Graphicx installed? I am not sure how to check whether I have it, but trying

```
tlmgr install graphicx
```

results in

```
package graphicx not present in package repository.
```

I'd appreciate any advice, framed at an introductory level.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarise yourself further with our format. Your `figure undefined` error is caused by using the `letter` document class; try `article` instead. You most likely have `graphicx` installed, but if not, it is known to `tlmgr` as `graphics`, as listed [here](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx). (Common packages are often uploaded to CTAN in lots of multiple packages which must be installed together.)

Comment: I think the error says that the *figure* environment is undefined, nothing about graphics. I'd suppose that `letter.cls` doesn't have a `figure` environment.  Do you need one?  You could do `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` instead.  (Two other things: what's with the weirdly placed `\centering` command? and your example file is missing the `\end{document}`.)

Comment: Thank you! Changing "letter" to "article" fixed the problem. I don't know if I can mark your comment as a "solution," but it worked. I'll also spend some time looking at the starter guide. I am enjoying using LaTeX a lot so far.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to use `tif` files. pdflatex can handle jpeg, png and PDF.

Comment: @ChrisS Would you like to write up a proper answer?

Comment: This could be a dupe of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25061/letter-class-alternatives-with-support-for-figures-tables-and-labels although perhaps you want a different answer or approach. For TIF images see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89989/add-tif-image-to-latex

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen I did discover that my `tif` file from my question produced an error---I switched over to a `png` file to solve that. I'm new to SE ... should I change that in the original question to prevent it being a red herring?

Comment: whether you are using letter or article you can just remove the `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` lines which are for making a floating insert for which latex chooses a good position. The image inclusion just needs `\includegraphics`. So change to article if you are writing an article not a letter, do not change to article for anything related to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error

> ERROR: LaTeX Error: Environment figure undefined.

is caused by the fact that the `letter` document class does not have a `figure` environment. Changing the document class to `article` solves this problem.

Answer (score 14):

Your documentclass `letter` does not define the environment `figure`.

This environment `figure` is in the most documentclasses a floating object, that means LaTeX has some freedom of where to place the content of `figure`. However, floating objects do not make much sense in short documents like letters, that's why `fugure` is not defined in letter.

If you want to include a graphic, you could do it like this:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

If you really want a floating `figure` environment in a `letter`, you can use the `float` and `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\newfloat{figure}{htbp}{figs}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption{Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is excellent info, but I'm promoting the simpler submission as my answer---as a beginner I'm just trying to get things to work, and the quickest, most-easily-implemented course is all I can manage right now.

Comment: the question is, do you want to write an article or a letter? If you want to write a letter, you should use a documentclass that suites it, so `letter` or maybe `scrlettr2` from komascript which is more suited for european tastes.