# control picture placement without figure environment in moderncv

Tags: graphics, moderncv

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\moderncvstyle{casual}                             
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               

\name{John}{Doe}


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\hbox{
    \hspace*{0.2\textwidth}
    \textcolor{color1}{\rule{5pt}{\textwidth}}
    \hspace*{0.05\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[]{/home/toogley/bew/img/passbilder/platzhalter.png}
}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: output]

I want to move the picture to the middle of the line. 
Normally, I'd try to solve that by using e.g. a `figure` environment. But when i use that here, i receive the error

```
LaTeX Error: Environment figure undefined.
```

According to [a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226821/76157), this error message means, i can't use it. Or rather, the only solution to use a figure environment, would be to change the way moderncv works.

**Therefore, my question is whether there's a way without changing how moderncv works.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `\hbox`; you're going to have surprises if you do.

Just shift down the rule and the picture. Don't forget to protect the end-of-lines.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\name{John}{Doe}


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\noindent
\hspace{0.2\textwidth}%
\textcolor{color1}{\rule[-.5\textwidth]{5pt}{\textwidth}}%
\hspace{0.05\textwidth}%
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-9x16}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can you explain why i shouldn't use `\hbox` ? Or provide some evidence/examples for that statement?

Comment: @toogley The comment was not specific to you: maybe you know about the quirks of `\hbox`, other readers may not.

Comment: I don't, therefore I'm asking. :D

Comment: @toogley `\hbox` doesn't start horizontal (paragraph) mode. Here it doesn't make much difference, in other cases it can. Try `<blank line>\hbox{abc}def`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that might work for you using `TikZ`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\moderncvstyle{casual}                             
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               

\name{John}{Doe}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[color1,line width=5pt] 
        ($(current page.north west)+(0.2\columnwidth,-2in)$)
        coordinate (TOP)
        -- ++ (0,-\textwidth)
        coordinate (BOT);
 \node[anchor=west] at ($(TOP)!0.50!(BOT)$)    {\includegraphics[width=1in]{no_you_cant}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By playing with the value `!0.50!` in

```
 \node[anchor=west] at ($(TOP)!0.25!(BOT)$)    {\includegraphics[width=1in]{no_you_cant}};
```

you can reposition the image to where you would like on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion using `\raisebox` to shift the picture upwards.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\moderncvstyle{casual}                             
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               

\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\hbox{%
    \hspace*{0.2\textwidth}%
    \textcolor{color1}{\rule{5pt}{\textwidth}}%
    \hspace*{0.05\textwidth}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-.5\height\relax}{%
      \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image-golden-upright}}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]