# How to make custom page frame using LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, header-footer, pst-barcode

I need to make questionnaire template for automatic processing with [queXF](http://quexf.sourceforge.net/). To do this I need to produce pages like this:

[image: Example of page with frame]

The queXF requirements for the pages are

- unique barcode for each page (done by using barcode as page number with help of packages `fancyhdr`, `pst-barcode`, `pstricks-add`)
- page frame for orientation

**I need** to draw the frame on each page like on the example page above (note that the frame is related to page, but not to text).

I see two ways for achieving this:

- to set an image background
- to draw separate lines (preferred)

Is it possible to do using LaTeX?

Comment: Found a hint in [answer to different question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/837/pdf-letterhead-as-document-background) for using background image:

    `\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{wallpaper}
    \ULCornerWallPaper{1}{background.pdf}
    \begin{document}
      Your text
    \end{document}`

But the solution without using additional files is still preferred.

Comment: You can draw the frame / lines with `pstricks`. To get the same position ate every site you can use the package `atbegshi` or the package `fancyhdr` which do you use.

Comment: I had tried using fancyhdr for this, but it moves text down, below frame. (Maybe I had done something wrong)

Comment: Please see: http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/background

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [background](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate some text

\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgVshift{-4}
\SetBgContents{
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw (0.55\textwidth,10) -- (0.55\textwidth,0.52\textheight) -- (0.4\textwidth,0.52\textheight);
\draw (-0.55\textwidth,10) -- (-0.55\textwidth,0.52\textheight) -- (-0.4\textwidth,0.52\textheight);
\draw (-0.55\textwidth,-10) -- (-0.55\textwidth,-0.52\textheight) -- (-0.4\textwidth,-0.52\textheight);
\draw (0.55\textwidth,-10) -- (0.55\textwidth,-0.52\textheight) -- (0.4\textwidth,-0.52\textheight);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]\newpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In relation to my comment here the adapted example with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\definecolor{myGray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\newdimen\BorderWidth \BorderWidth=\paperwidth
\newdimen\BorderHeight \BorderHeight=\paperheight
\newdimen\BorderSep \BorderSep=30pt
\advance\BorderWidth by -2\BorderSep

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Border{%
  \psset{unit=1pt}
  \put(\strip@pt\BorderSep,\strip@pt\BorderHeight){%
    \advance\BorderHeight by -\BorderSep
%    \psframe[linewidth=3pt]%
%     (0,-\BorderHeight)(\BorderWidth, -\BorderSep)
    \psline(0,-0.25\BorderWidth)(0,-\BorderSep)(0.25\BorderWidth,-\BorderSep)
    \psline(0.75\BorderWidth,-\BorderSep)(\BorderWidth,-\BorderSep)(\BorderWidth,-.25\BorderWidth)
    \@tempdima -\BorderHeight
    \advance\@tempdima .25\BorderWidth
    \psline(0,\@tempdima)(0,-\BorderHeight)(.25\BorderWidth,-\BorderHeight)
    \psline(0.75\BorderWidth,-\BorderHeight)(\BorderWidth,-\BorderHeight)(\BorderWidth,\@tempdima)
}}
\makeatother
\AddToShipoutPicture{\Border}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```