# Multiple border around page

Tags: margins, framed

I was thinking about giving a finishing touch to my resume by adding a `border` to the document in black color. I tried using `\fancybox` but not impressed with the output.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin={20mm,20mm},hmargin={20mm,20mm}, includehead,%
 includefoot]{geometry}
 \usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}

\fancypage{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox}{}

Document text goes here...

\end{document}
```

The output that I am trying to get is something similar like this.

[image]

How do  I get multiple recessed rectangle covering the whole page ?

Comment: See the package `background`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26957/how-to-make-custom-page-frame-using-latex

Comment: Another possibility: the [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,heightrounded]{geometry}
%
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [line width=1pt,rounded corners=7pt,
        ]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (1cm,-1cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-1cm,1cm) $);
        \draw [xshift=4mm,dashed,line width=1pt,rounded corners=7pt]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (.5cm,-.5cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-.5cm,.5cm) $);
    \draw [line width=1pt,rounded corners=7pt]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (1.5cm,-1.5cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.5cm,1.5cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

With `background`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,heightrounded]{geometry}
%
\usepackage{background}
%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgContents{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [line width=1pt,rounded corners=7pt,
        ]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (1cm,-1cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-1cm,1cm) $);
        \draw [xshift=4mm,dashed,line width=1pt,rounded corners=7pt]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (.5cm,-.5cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-.5cm,.5cm) $);
    \draw [line width=1pt,rounded corners=7pt]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (1.5cm,-1.5cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.5cm,1.5cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked, I modified the layout and now I can get the result I wanted, I am using the `tikz` package and its cool. However the `margin/border` doesn't extend to second page and stays in the first page itself. How do I make it extended to n number of pages ?

Comment: @Shashwat: Use the `background` version of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is the code that I am using in the `resume`, pasting the code after `\newpage` creates line at multiple pages.

```
\usepackage[a4,frame]{crop}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%%%
%%%The code below will help us draw borders.
%%%
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw [line width=3pt,rounded corners=1pt,]
    ($ (current page.north west) + (1cm,-1cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-1cm,1cm) $);       
\end{tikzpicture}

%%%Till here 
%%%
%%%
```

Thanks everyone who helped me complete my resume.

[image]