# How to draw a simple 1mm thick page frame?

Tags: tikz-pgf, framed, mdframed

I'm trying to make a simple one-line 1mm thick page frame. Left line of that frame should be 2.5cm from edge and all other lines 0.5cm. Document includes tikz drawing, and text.

The problem is that I'm failing to make any frame that is not sticked to the content or drawn by dimensions mentioned above.

I think that this could be made by using packages like frame, or mdframed, but since I've just recently started using LaTeX, I find them a bit difficult to comprehend.

Comment: Hi Wakko, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Have a look at [How to set colored ruled margins for different pages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73480) and let us know if it helps :)

Comment: Could you add a Minimum Working Example (MWE) of the code you have so far to your question?

Comment: Do you want to draw this frame for a single page, or for all the pages in the document?

Comment: Try the package `crop` with the option `frame`.

Comment: @Sigur : Thanks, but I forgot to mention, that I tried that as well. I've just gone through the crop documentation once again and I haven't found any method of specifying the distance of line of of the edge.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I need this for not more than one to two pages.

Comment: @Wakko, you have to change the paper size to see some effect. But if you want a local frame, for only some pages, this is not a good idea.

Comment: The `fancybox` package should be able to do simple frames; see also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73611/multiple-border-around-page)

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much. That link was really helpful :D

Answer (score 6):

Since you're already using `tikz` here's an example which makes use of *overlays* from that package.
(See page 200 in the manual for more details).  You do need to run this through LaTeX twice to get the placement to be correct.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node (A) [xshift=2.5cm,yshift=0.5cm] at (current page.south west) {};
    \node (B) [xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm] at (current page.north west) {};
    \node (C) [xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm] at (current page.north east) {};
    \node (D) [xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm] at (current page.south east) {};

    \coordinate (cA) at (A) ;
    \coordinate (cB) at (B);
    \coordinate (cC) at (C);
    \coordinate (cD) at (D) ;


    \draw[line width=1mm] (cA) -- (cB) -- (cC) -- (cD) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You could place the `tikzpicture` in a command `\myborderedpage` and then call it on the pages where you want the border:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\myborderedpage}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node (A) [xshift=2.5cm,yshift=0.5cm] at (current page.south west) {};
    \node (B) [xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm] at (current page.north west) {};
    \node (C) [xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm] at (current page.north east) {};
    \node (D) [xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm] at (current page.south east) {};

    \coordinate (cA) at (A) ;
    \coordinate (cB) at (B);
    \coordinate (cC) at (C);
    \coordinate (cD) at (D) ;


    \draw[line width=1mm] (cA) -- (cB) -- (cC) -- (cD) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]

\myborderedpage

\lipsum[21-40]

\myborderedpage

\end{document}
```

If you're willing to load another `tikz` library, the following code is a bit simpler and less convoluted than the above examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\myborderedpage}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw [line width=1mm]
            ($ (current page.south west) + (2.5cm,0.5cm) $)
            rectangle
            ($ (current page.north east) + (-0.5cm, -0.5cm)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]

\myborderedpage

\lipsum[21-40]

\myborderedpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you :D That was helpful... I have managed to finish my work.