# How may i add a paper stucture?

Tags: graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PDF letterhead as document background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/837/pdf-letterhead-as-document-background)

Does anybody know, how to get a paper structure like shown at
http://www.tsengbooks.com/showbooks.html ?

I've heard this would be possible by using the package `atbegshi`
but I have really no idea how to use `atbegshi` to get such a paper
structure. Has anybody an idea?

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: To clarify: are you asking how to set a background image to get a paper texture effect? If so, the `wallpaper` (or perhaps `background`) package would be a better choice than `atbegshi`; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/837/6984.

Comment: Thanks to you both. I will take a look at the wallpaper package.

Comment: @schmendrich: If the answer given by Eric was what you needed, then please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 7):

The **`wallpaper`** package is exactly what you're looking for

```
\usapackage{wallpaper}
```

More information is in the [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wallpaper/wallpapermanual.pdf) and in the [example folder](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wallpaper/example) on CTAN.