# Reproducing an official letterhead

Tags: positioning, header-footer

My university, just like many other institutions, isn't really aware of something called LaTeX. Therefore, the letterhead comes only in MS Word. The following (low quality) image is the best guide I have that describes the measurements, margins, and fonts. I will need to reproduce the letterhead (some measurements are, at best, odd).

[image: WSU Letterhead]

The University's logo is available at [WSU visual identity web site](http://identity.wsu.edu/downloads/pullman/academic-signatures.aspx) as shown below

[image: WSU logo]

I know I can place the logo at the prescribed location using `textpos` package, but how can I add the horizontal line and the flushright text?

Comment: You can convert the Word template to PDF and put the PDF in the background as shown here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/837/pdf-letterhead-as-document-background but obviously you won't get all the perks of typesetting in LaTeX.

Comment: The first thing I would do would be to edit the logo to remove the included rule. Trying to overlay one on / in extension of another is often a recipe for issues...

Comment: As an employee at WSU and work with this kind of stuff, I think you may be breaking usage since the templates and other resources are for over-arching units, and not individual people. The primary exception to this is for department heads, directors, deans, etc. To be honest I'm surprised that publishing said to go with it. They have denied our unit and any other unit I've known on campus to do stuff on our own. Ed Sala is a good guy though, so if he said go for it then I guess its okay. Your best bet though is to really talk to your departments marketing person, cant remember her name but she

Comment: Why not save the Word template as a .pdf and then import it as a background picture in LaTeX? That way, you would have everything right as they want it. I would suggest you export one plain version and one with all the dummy text, so you can set up your page layout exactly like theirs.

Comment: There seem to be [a solution for this using KOMA-Script letter class `scrlttr2`](http://komascript.de/node/1599).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**See the edit below.**

Here's my first attempt at this. The code is reasonably commentated but essentially I'm using `textpos` for placing the logo, `tikz` for adding the extra horizontal line, and `geometry` to set the margins. The subheader is placed using `textpos` and `\hfill`. The footer is placed at the bottom of the page using `\vfill`. This works for one-page letters, but not for longer letters (which will hopefully be avoided anyways). A better solution might be to use `fancyhdr`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvinames]{xcolor}
% Measurements are taken directly from the guide
\usepackage[top=2in,left=1.5in,bottom=0.5in,right=0.625in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,
            pdfborder={0 0 0},
            ]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
% A nice serif font, but no the prescribed nonfree ITC stone
\usepackage[oldstylenums]{kpfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% No paragraph indentation
\parindent0pt
\setlength{\parskip}{0.8\baselineskip}
\raggedright
\pagestyle{empty}
% Define WSU official colors
\definecolor{WSUcrimson}{RGB}{152,30,50}
\definecolor{WSUgray}{HTML}{5e6a71}
% Ensure consistency in the footer
\urlstyle{sf}

\begin{document}

Date
\bigskip

Prof.~Wisman\\
Department of Wisemen\\
Wise State University \\
Wisetown, Wise\ \ 12345-6789\\
USA

Dear Prof.~Wiseman:

% Write the body of the letter
\lipsum[1]

Sincerely,
\vspace{4\baselineskip}

Me Myselfovsky \\
Assistant Professor


% -------------------------------------------------------
% Add logo, the text under the crimson line, and the line itself
\begin{textblock*}{2in}[0.3066,0.39](1.5in,1.33in)
    \includegraphics[width=2in]{WSUlogo}
\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{6.375in}(1.5in,1.4in)   % 6.375=8.5 - 1.5 - 0.625
    \sffamily
    \hfill \color{WSUgray} School of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science\\
    \hfill Dr.~Me Myselfovsky, Assistant Professor
\end{textblock*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[color=WSUcrimson,line width=1pt] (current page.north west)+(1.5in,-1.33in) -- ($(-0.625in,-1.33in)+(current page.north east)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

% Add the footnote. A better way would be to use fancyhdr
\vfill
{\footnotesize\color{WSUgray}\sffamily
PO Box 642752, Pullman, WA 99164-2752\\[-0.1\baselineskip]
(509) 335-6249 \textbullet\ Fax: (509) 335-3818 \textbullet\ \url{me@eecs.wsu.edu} \textbullet\ \url{http://eecs.wsu.edu/~me}
}
\end{document}
```

Here's the result:
[image: WSU Letterhead in LaTeX]

---

### EDIT

---

The following is a better way to do this. The common definitions are put in a separate file. Headers and footers are used to place the letterhead components, so there is no problem with letters that are longer than one page. `\AtBeginDocument` and `\AtEndDocument` are used to place the salutation and signature. The actual letter just needs to `\input` these definitions and add appropriate `\renewcommand`s.

### EDIT 2

The missing `}` at the end of the Common Definitions code block as been fixed.

### Common Definitions:

```
% Define WSU official colors
\usepackage[dvinames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{WSUcrimson}{RGB}{152,30,50}
\definecolor{WSUgray}{HTML}{5e6a71}

% Measurements are taken directly from the guide
\usepackage[top=2in,left=1.5in,bottom=0.5in,right=0.625in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,
            pdfborder={0 0 0},
            ]{hyperref}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{soul}


% --- For placement of the horizontal line
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% --- A nice serif font (palatino), but not the prescribed nonfree ITC stone
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}

% Remove paragraph indentation
\parindent0pt
\setlength{\parskip}{0.8\baselineskip}
\raggedright
\pagestyle{empty}
% Ensure consistency in the footer
\urlstyle{sf}

\providecommand\WSUfromname{Me Myselfovsky}
\providecommand\WSUfromtitle{Assistant Professor}
\providecommand\WSUfromdegree{Ph.D.}
\providecommand\WSUfromdept{School of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science}
\providecommand\WSUfromaddress{PO Box 642752, Pullman, WA 99164-2752}
\providecommand\WSUfromtel{(509) 335-5555}
\providecommand\WSUfromfax{(509) 335-6666}
\providecommand\WSUfromemail{\url{me@eecs.wsu.edu}}
\providecommand\WSUfromweb{\url{http://eecs.wsu.edu/~me}}
\providecommand\WSUtoname{Dr.~Wiseman}
\providecommand\WSUtoaddress{Department of Wisemen\\
                            Wise State University \\
                            Wisetown, Wise\ \ 12345-6789\\
                            USA}
\providecommand\WSUdate{\today}
\providecommand\WSUopening{Dear \WSUtoname}
\providecommand\WSUclosing{Sincerely}
% Update this and the next line to the correct path
\providecommand\WSUsignaturefile{AleeSignatureVector}
\providecommand\WSUlogofile{WSUlogo}
\providecommand\WSUenclosure{}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[L]{%
    {\footnotesize\color{WSUgray}\sffamily
    \WSUfromaddress\\[-0.1\baselineskip]
    \WSUfromtel\ \textbullet\ Fax: \WSUfromfax\ \textbullet\ \WSUfromemail\ \textbullet\ \WSUfromweb}\color{black}}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{%
    \begin{textblock*}{2in}[0.3066,0.39](1.5in,1.33in)
        \includegraphics[width=2in]{\WSUlogofile}
    \end{textblock*}
    \begin{textblock*}{6.375in}(1.5in,1.4in)   % 6.375=8.5 - 1.5 - 0.625
        \sffamily
        \hfill \color{WSUgray} \WSUfromdept
        \\ \hfill \WSUfromname, \WSUfromdegree
    \end{textblock*}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw[color=WSUcrimson,line width=0.7pt] (current page.north west)+(1.5in,-1.33in) -- ($(-0.625in,-1.33in)+(current page.north east)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\AtBeginDocument{
    % Text lines should be less than 6in long
    \newgeometry{top=2in,left=1.5in,bottom=1.2in,right=1in}

    \WSUdate
    \bigskip

    \WSUtoname\ifthenelse{\equal{\WSUtoname}{}}{}{\\}
    \WSUtoaddress
    \bigskip

    \WSUopening\par
    }

\AtEndDocument{
    \par\vspace{2ex}
    \WSUclosing,

    \ifthenelse{\equal{\WSUsignaturefile}{}}{\bigskip\bigskip}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in]{\WSUsignaturefile}\\[-0.2\baselineskip]}

    \WSUfromname \\
    \WSUfromtitle\ifthenelse{\equal{\WSUfromtitle}{}}{}{\\}
    \WSUenclosure
    }
```

### Letter Body:

This can be as simple as the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\input{WSUletterdefs}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `ragged2e` would give better non-justified text.  (And I really hope that WSU doesn't insist that the textblock must not be justified.)

Comment: @jon, thanks for `ragged2e`. Another look at the image above shows the WSU does not really use the right margin for text, only for the horizontal line. See, for example, the first line of letter body where "the" is moved to the next line.

Comment: note that there is a brace missing at the end of **Common Definitions**

Comment: @NathanMusoke, thanks. Fixed!

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to check WSU's usage guidelines to make sure you are not violating any rules, my guess is you are, with respect to the logo usage. Assuming you can legally use the logo on your desired version the letter head layout, I wouldn't use LaTeX exclusively for the layout. The problem I see is the line in the logo. A pure LaTeX solution would require adding a perfectly matched line (color, thickness, and position) to extend the existing line. I would modify extend the line in the logo to be the full page width in a vector graphics program (e.g., Inkscape or Illustrator). I would also add the text in the matched color and font to the line. I would also create a vector graphic version of the footer with matched color and font. The advantage of making the header and footers into images is that you do not need to have the corresponding font installed on all computers that will compile the letters. It also means you do not always have to use `xelatex`.

Once you have these two images adding them to the header (flush right to get the overhang into the left margin) and footer (flush left) at the approraite heights can be done with `fancyhdr`. You can then use any font in the text body.

Comment: why would you think I'm violating WSU's usage rules with respect to logo? And what's illegal about using the letterhead for my correspondence? Also, the Word template itself uses text, not pictures, for the footer and header, so I don't think that would be a major issue.

Comment: @AliMehrizi A quick look at the website (http://identity.wsu.edu/stationery/default.aspx) reveals: "To maintain a consistent graphic identity, the University Publishing should produce all stationery."

Comment: I have clearly looked at that before `:-)`. And I talked to the director of publishing. As I long as I reproduce what they have, there's no problem.  My LaTeX template adheres more religiously to these guidelines than many "official" letters I've eye witnessed.

Comment: I changed the thickness of the line to match 0.7 pt of the original. Mistakenly I had it at 1 pt before.

Comment: @AliMehrizi. I tried to run your nice example, but apparently I receive an error message. I copied the input file, the logo and the signature (my signature is a png file) into the same folder and I renamed them in the same way you did. What I got is the following: Runaway argument?
{ \par \vspace {2ex} \WSUclosing , \par \ifthenelse {\equal {\WSUsignaturefile 
\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \g@addto@macro.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.5 \input{WSUletterdefs}. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AliMehrizi. Found the mistake. In the common definitions file, you missed a } at the very end of your tex.