# Beautiful letterhead

Tags: header-footer, letters, article, letterhead

How can I create a beautiful letterhead from the `article` class using say header or footer .  I do not want to use `letter` class due to limitations. The letterhead should look outstanding.

Comment: Can you define outstanding? Should it be out of the margins? :P

Comment: Use scrlttr2, provided by the KOMA-script bundle. There is an extensive manual and I can not think of any letterhead which can not be realised with it.

Comment: There are a number of good letterhead questions on the site, any one of which might count as a duplicate. [Reproducing an official letterhead](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59932/2693) • 
[Business letter template with letterhead on the side](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55928/2693) •
[Creating letters with zero-margin colored headers, in addition to the regular letterhead](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43983/2693)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 6):

I have produced a letterhead as an article by using the package `textpos` and setting the origin of the paper to the lower left corner as the origin as well as using mm as a unit:

```
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos} % Positioning textblocks in absolute terms
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\textblockorigin{0mm}{0mm}
```

This then allows me to insert text such as the date, to and from addresses as text fields at exact positions using textblocks, in this case placing the page number and the date (note that the page number uses the `lastpage` package)

```
\begin{textblock}{5}(195,13)
\thepage(\pageref{LastPage})
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{25}(114,35)
\today
\end{textblock}
```

I also add graphics using the `put` command. I actually define logos as new commands to manage them more easily

```
\newcommand\FirstPageLogo{%
   \put(99,730){%
       \includegraphics[width=33mm,keepaspectratio]{logo-org-english_rgb.pdf}%
     }}
```

Note that in ths example the coordinates are in pt as determined by the `\unitlength` parameter but this can be changed by `\setlength`.

Using these code snippets you can place all parts of the letterhead components exactly where you want. There may be other ways of doing the same but I found this relatively straight forward.