# Template for American Journal of Psychiatry

Tags: templates

At https://ajp.psychiatryonline.org/ajp_ifora I find a detailed list of requirements associated with submitting an article to the American Journal of Psychiatry:

> All parts of the manuscript or letter to the Editor, including case
>   reports, quotations, references, and tables, must be double-spaced
>   throughout. The manuscript should be arranged in the following order,
>   with each item beginning a new page: 1) cover letter, 2) title page,
>   3) abstract, 4) text, 5) references, and 6) tables and/or figures. All
>   pages must be numbered.
>
> COVER LETTER
>
> The cover letters should include statements regarding
>   Authorship, Disclosure, and Copyright Transfer. Also, it must include
>   a list of 4 suggested reviewers and their e-mail addresses.
>
> TITLE PAGE
>
> Word count. The number of words in the manuscript (including abstract,
>   text, and references) and the number of tables and figures should be
>   noted in the upper right-hand corner of the title page. Tables and
>   figures are no longer included in the word count.
>
> Title. The title should be informative and as brief as possible.
>   Journal style for titles is not to use declarative sentences.
>
> Byline. See instructions for Authorship. Authors’ first names are
>   preferred over initials. Degrees should be included after each
>   author’s name.
>
> Previous presentation. If the paper has been presented at a meeting,
>   give the name of the meeting, the location, and the inclusive dates.
>
> Location of work and address for reprints. Provide the department,
>   institution, city, and state where the work was done. Include a full
>   address for the author who is to receive correspondence and reprint
>   requests.
>
> Disclosures and acknowledgments. In a separate paragraph, all
>   potential conflicts of interest...

I used the apa6e documentclass to write an article which gives me some of these requirements very nicely, but I'd like to incorporate the cover letter and the title page as described here too (with continuous page numbering in all 6 sections). My documentclass gives me a titlepage (with `\maketitle`) but it doesn't create all the other fields required above (word count, location of work and address for reprints, disclosures, et. al.). I used a `\authornote` for a kind of disclosure, and I suppose it would suffice, but how can I create all these other fields? I realize that word count is difficult to automate, so I could fill it in by hand, but creating a field for it on the title page is beyond my skills. Plus, handling the continuous page-numbering throughout all six sections of the document escapes me too.

Is there another documentclass for such a manuscript submission that would contain all these sections and fields? How do other folks do this?

## EDIT 1

So I've been strugging with this in my spare time since posting, and my comment below about just using a `\newpage` is clearly rather naive. I suppose that the typesetting engine sees all this text before the title page as just more article whereas what I really need is some kind of letter environment or documentclass within my existing documentclass of apa6e.

For example, I need to be able to write a nicely formatted letter with originating address, recipient address, salutation, body, closing, signature block, and all that.

I know I could write a separate document using a letter documentclass, but I need the page-numbering to be continuous (see AJP requirements above).

So if there's no existing documentclass to handle submitting a manuscript to AJP using LaTeX, then does anyone know how I can make a special environment within my existing documentclass that will allow me to easily write a simple cover letter?

## EDIT 2

The cover letter should look like this, but according to the requirements, it must be the first page of the entire document with a continuous (contiguous?) page-numbering scheme from item 1 (cover letter) to item 6 (tables and/or figures). I have only items 1-5 (no tables or figures), and items 3, 4, and 5 are perfectly handled by the apa6e documentclass, but the title page (though almost complete according to these requirements) is not quite complete, lacking a word count field and a table/figure count field in the upper right-hand corner of the title page. I would fill in the word count by hand, of course, as I think all the automatic word count programs are not quite perfectly accurate.

[image: Sample Cover Letter Image]

Comment: This template is apparently created with MS Word in mind. You can use the center environment or any other formatting of your choice without a need for specific fields.

Comment: This might have been a bit of a silly question. I just added a `\newpage` before `\maketitle` which added a blank page before the title page, which I suppose will allow me to typeset a cover letter by hand there with whatever detail I wish. Unfortunately, this page incorporates the "Running head" text from the apa6e documentclass, but perhaps that's not such a big deal (although I would like to suppress it if possible on that page). This feels like a rather ugly hack, but it might suffice for my needs. I still welcome other ideas though.

Comment: Can you post a picture of what pages should look like with the appropriate settings?

Comment: Can't you use `pdfpages` to include the letter along, say along with a `\thispagestyle{empty}`..?

Comment: Adding the letter and including it in the page numbering is simple.  See [Change document class per page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89792) for an example.

Comment: jon I may be able to do that, but I'm unfamiliar with `pdfpages`, so I'll check that out. Thanks for the suggestion. @AlanMunn thanks for the Change document class per page suggestion. I'll have a look at that too. Unfortunately, I think that still may leave unaddressed the title page changes (word count and table/figure count) although I hope that when I look at your suggestion more carefully, I'll be wrong on this point too. Thanks very much for the ideas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a cover letter as shown except for the date location (maybe someone can advice us on how to change its location unless that doesn't matter).

In the main document, you add `\usepackage{pdfpages}` and where you want the letter you put `\includepdf[pages = 1]{coverletter.pdf}`.  The `pages =` option is what page you want to insert the cover letter.

Here is a link to the package documentation: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% Margins                                                                           
\topmargin = -1in
\textheight = 8.5in
\oddsidemargin = -10pt
\textwidth = 6.5in
\let\raggedleft\raggedright
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{
    My Name\\
    U of Research\\
    Some address\\
    Some city, state, and zip code\\
    Some phone number\\
    My e-mail address\\
    \medskip
    Dr. John Edit\\
    Editor-in-Chief\\
    \textit{Journal of Science}
  }
  \signature{
    My Name\\
    Professor, Dep ...\\
    U of Research
  }
  \opening{Dear Dr. Edit:}
  \lipsum[2-4]
  \closing{Sincerely,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here was a sample `main.tex` I created.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tocloft}
% this section enclosed was lifted from Alan Munn
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%-------------------------------------------------
\cfoot{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents

\includepdf[addtotoc = {1, section, 1, Cover Letter, coverl}, pagecommand =
{\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{coverletter.pdf}
% addtotoc has {section number (first so it occurs after the toc, 
% type it could chapter, section, etc, level refers to chapter...,
% the name in toc, and reference label

\section{Two}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Since this was 3 pages, I had to take unorthodox pictures to show it achieves your request.

Table of Contents correctly ordered:

[image]

---

Bottom of TOC page with letter following:

[image]

---

Bottom of the letter page numbered in correct order:

[image]

---

Bottom of the letter followed by the first section which has been indexed to the section 2.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @dustin. I'll try this out tomorrow and let you know. Any thoughts on changes to the title page though (see edit 2 in Q)?

Comment: Wow, your solution does indeed make a very nice cover letter for me. Thanks so much for introducing me to `pdfpages`!

Answer (score 4):

Dustin has given you a layout for a letter. Here's some commands to modify the title page of the `apa6e` class so that the other information is included.  I have created the following new commands:

- `\coverletter{}` the filename of the PDF coverletter
- `\wordcount{}` the word count of the document (you must supply this value)
- `\previous{}` place of previous presentation
- `\address{}` corresponding author's address
- `\disclosures{}` any disclosures

Each of these needs to be provided a value for the document to compile correctly.

Note that counting words in LaTeX is a non-trivial task. See:

- [Is there any way to do a correct word count of a LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/534/2693)

For some other options on letters in LaTeX see:

- [Letter class alternatives with support for figures, tables, and labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25061/2693)
- [Business letter template with letterhead on the side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55928/2693)
- [Reproducing an official letterhead](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59932/2693)

It's not clear from your description whether the letter should have a numbered page or not, or just be included in the page numbering (so that the title page is numbered 2).  Also, since the word count occupies the top right hand corner it's not clear whether the title page itself should have a number.)

---

### Code

```
\documentclass{apa6e}
\usepackage{pdfpages} % to include the cover letter
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for dummy text in this example
\makeatletter
% define new commands to meet Am. J. Psych.
\newcommand{\coverletter}[1]{\def\@coverletter{#1}}
\newcommand{\wordcount}[1]{\long\def\word@count{#1}}
\newcommand{\previous}[1]{\long\def\@previous{#1}}
\newcommand{\address}[1]{\long\def\@address{#1}}
\newcommand{\disclosures}[1]{\long\def\@disclosures{#1}}
% need to redefine fancyhdr's head command to use [t] aligned par boxes
\def\@fancyhead#1#2#3#4#5{#1\hbox to\headwidth{\fancy@reset
  \@fancyvbox\headheight{\hbox
    {\rlap{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\raggedright#2}}\hfill
      \parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\centering#3}\hfill
      \llap{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\raggedleft#4}}}\headrule}}#5}
% redefine the title page style to include the word count
\fancypagestyle{titlepage}{%
\setlength{\headheight}{2\baselineskip}
\lhead{Running head: \MakeUppercase{\@shorttitle}}
\rhead{\word@count}}
% redefine \maketitle to include the extra fields
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\includepdf[pages=1-,offset={-.5in 0in}]{\@coverletter}
\thispagestyle{titlepage}%
\vspace*{1in}%
\Centering\@title\\\@author
\vfil%
\RaggedRight
\@previous
\vfil
\@address
\vfil%
\@disclosures
\vfil
\ifdefined%
  \apaSIXe@leavefloats%
  {\large\textbf{\textit{A helpful reminder, courtesy \texttt{apa6e.cls}:} Figures and tables are currently mixed in with
      your text for easier reading. Don't forget to remove the
      \texttt{leavefloats} option before you submit!}\vfill}%
\fi
Author Note\par\RaggedRight\@authornote%
\mspart{Abstract}%
\@abstract%
\mspart{\@title}}
\makeatother

% You need to supply all of the following:
\title{The title of the paper}
\shorttitle{Short title}
\author{An Author}
\previous{This was previously presented at a big conference.}
% Address is best put in a tabular (but not required)
\address{
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
University of Somewhere\\
Psych Building\\
Somewhere
\end{tabular}
}
\wordcount{2000 words\\2 tables\\3 figures}
\disclosures{I am not funded by Big Pharma.}
\abstract{\kant[2]}
\authornote{}
\coverletter{myletter.pdf} % fill in the name of your letter PDF here
% once these are defined \maketitle does the rest
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\kant[3]
\end{document}
```

### Packaging this as a package

These kinds of modifications are best put into a package.  Save the following as `ajp.sty` in your local `texmf` directory and then you can eliminate all the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (including those commands) and replace it with:

```
\usepackage{ajp}
```

#### ajp.sty

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{ajp}[2013/08/16 Extra stuff for American Journal of Psychiatry v 1.0]
\@ifclassloaded{apa6e}{}
{\PackageError{apj}
  {This package assumes you are using the apa6e class}
  {Please load the apa6e class.}}
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}
% define new commands to meet Am. J. Psych.
\newcommand{\coverletter}[1]{\def\@coverletter{#1}}
\newcommand{\wordcount}[1]{\long\def\word@count{#1}}
\newcommand{\previous}[1]{\long\def\@previous{#1}}
\newcommand{\address}[1]{\long\def\@address{#1}}
\newcommand{\disclosures}[1]{\long\def\@disclosures{#1}}
% need to redefine fancyhdr's head command to use [t] aligned par boxes
\def\@fancyhead#1#2#3#4#5{#1\hbox to\headwidth{\fancy@reset
  \@fancyvbox\headheight{\hbox
    {\rlap{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\raggedright#2}}\hfill
      \parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\centering#3}\hfill
      \llap{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\raggedleft#4}}}\headrule}}#5}
% redefine the title page style to include the word count
\fancypagestyle{titlepage}{%
\setlength{\headheight}{2\baselineskip}
\lhead{Running head: \MakeUppercase{\@shorttitle}}
\rhead{\word@count}}
% redefine \maketitle to include the extra fields
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\includepdf[pages=1-,offset={-.5in 0in}]{\@coverletter}
\thispagestyle{titlepage}%
\vspace*{1in}%
\Centering\@title\\\@author
\vfil%
\RaggedRight
\@previous
\vfil
\@address
\vfil%
\@disclosures
\vfil
\ifdefined%
  \apaSIXe@leavefloats%
  {\large\textbf{\textit{A helpful reminder, courtesy \texttt{apa6e.cls}:} Figures and tables are currently mixed in with
      your text for easier reading. Don't forget to remove the
      \texttt{leavefloats} option before you submit!}\vfill}%
\fi
Author Note\par\RaggedRight\@authornote%
\mspart{Abstract}%
\@abstract%
\mspart{\@title}}
\endinput
```

---

### Output of first 4 pages

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you. I thought I would be able to try out Dustin's suggestion today but was not able to after all. I will certainly try both answers tomorrow. Thanks very much for both of your inputs.

Comment: Wonderful solution, Alan! Thanks so much for making it so simple that even a newbie like me could figure it out. I had to study it for awhile, but it works like a charm so between Dustin's cover letter part and your title page modifications, I have exactly what I need. I cannot thank you enough for the help! :)