# How to insert powerpoint slide into LaTeX file

Tags: graphics, backgrounds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PDF letterhead as document background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/837/pdf-letterhead-as-document-background)

I have an image stored in powerpoint . I want to use it as my background in my pdf produced from LaTeX. What can I do so that I can export the image in my LaTeX file ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Try to save the image as PDF from power point.

Comment: Actually I want to set the image as my background in pdf. If I use \includegraphics{name of the pdf} , then I cannot add anything on the image. What command should I use so that I can do this ?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [How to create a background image on title page with LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46280/12850). Note that the answers work not only on the title page.

Comment: Is it possible to type text on iamge ?

Comment: Have you looked at the answers to the question I linked? They show ways of putting an image into the background without disturbing normal typesetting.

Comment: @StephanLehmke : i have seen the answers but it somehow show nothing in my latex pdf

Comment: @anonymous Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. This means the source of the document which is not working for you, stripped of everything not neccessary for showing the problem.

Comment: @anonymous: As Stephan suggested, it would be good to have a MWE to better understand the problem. But, if your problem is only how to draw or write something over a pdf image, you can read [drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `eso-pic` package. Save the Powerpoint as PDF and use `eso-pic` to put it in the background. See also the following question [background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46280/how-to-create-a-background-image-on-title-page-with-latex)