# How to insert a pdf as background?

Tags: pdf, titles, backgrounds

I want to use a pdf page as background for a title page. The pdfpages package does a good job inserting the page, but I can't write my content on it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Package `background` might help

Comment: You may try solutions described into the [LaTeX wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Page_background)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDF letterhead as document background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/837/pdf-letterhead-as-document-background)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need the package `eso-pic` ([eso-pic package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic?lang=en))

`\usepackage{eso-pic}`

Before `\begin{document}`, define:

```latex
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{
    \put(0,0){
    \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
    \vfill
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{BackGroundPDF.pdf}
    \vfill
    }}}
```

After `\begin{document}`:

```latex
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}
 \maketitle
```

the `*` states that the background picture is only used on that page.

Answer (score 5):

I recently encountered this problem and I found the solution from https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=26829 works better for me. Since this question here pops out on the top when I search for it. It may be beneficial to also have the code here.

It uses the package `background`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{letter}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{scale = 1, angle = 0, opacity = 0.2,
   contents = {\includegraphics[width = \paperwidth,
   height = \paperheight, keepaspectratio]
   {Background.pdf}}}
\begin{document}
Main text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please make your code compilable.