# How can I make an image background? And how can I change the standard color from black?

Tags: color, backgrounds

I want to make an image background in Overleaf and I have no I idea how to do that.

I want to be able to write over it just like one can change background color with `\pagecolor{color}`, I also want to change the color of the text so as to be white in the output but I don't want to use `\textcolor{white}{}` every time I write something.

Is there a way to make white the standard color?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please add a little example of your code? As is, your question is a bit generic: what document class are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a background image on title page with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46280/how-to-create-a-background-image-on-title-page-with-latex) or [How to insert a pdf as background?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278620/how-to-insert-a-pdf-as-background) or [PDF letterhead as document background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/837/277964)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `eso-pic` and `\color`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}}

\begin{document}\color{white}
  It is not clear if you would like only one page with background or more.
  \newpage
  This example shows all pages with background.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "It is not clear if you would like only one page with background or more" I want all of pages to have the same background

Comment: @Mathematicsenjoyer My example is OK, then. Thank you for accepting my answer.

Comment: this will not make everything white as it doesn't change `\normalcolor`. E.g. look at the page number which is still black. If everything should be white move the `\color{white}` into the preamble, then `\normalcolor` will pick that up at begin document.

Comment: @Mathematicsenjoyer Would you like the page numbers black or white?

Comment: I am facing a problem that the image of the background color seem to have some kind of whitish effect (I mean its color seem  to be more white that the original image  )

Comment: @Mathematicsenjoyer Try with `eso-pic`, see my renewed answer.